# Add data on the client side to Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using Jqgrid to show some data, using DataType as local, I don't want to post back to the server and return jsonString with the data to bind. I am passing the Json String to the client and adding the data one by one using addRowData. It seems it is taking a noticeable time to the user if the number of the data is big due to the information I have in each cell.

```
   for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++)
       jQuery("#jqgInventory").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, JSON.parse(gridData[i]));
```

Is there any alternative way to bind the data to jqgrid, for example just give it the JsonString as a datasource and it will bind it faster or any other suggestion.

Note: Using DataType as Json and setting the postUrl will work faster than the above method.

please any help !
Thanks in advance,
Alaa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sentence comes directly from the jqGrid documentation: "A array that store the local data passed to the grid. You can directly point to this variable in case you want to load a array data. It can replace addRowData method which is slow on relative big data".  That is exactly what you are talking about.

See it here: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Here is your working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/649/

You simply have to put in the option:

```
data: my_data
```

Where `my_data` is the array of information.

Comment: +1 from me. Your answer is correct. I would recommend you only 1) include `gridview: true` in the list of grid options to improve the performance, 2) add `height: 'auto'` to improve visibility and 3) either add `rowNum` option with large value like `10000` or add the pager to the grid. For example add `toppager: true`. The code without pager will just shows per default the first 20 rows (dafault value of `rowNum`) and cut the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, yes I just addressed the problem brought up in the question.  I also recommend using a pager or increasing the max rows shown.  I just took that example from the jqgrid examples: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html.  Under loading data -> Array data and converted it to use the `data` parameter.  For some reason they use the `addRowData` convention in the example... probably hasn't been updated in a while.

Comment: Oops, i found the right example, under "New in version 3.7", it also has a pager, I will update the fiddle.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: I agree that the information from [the official jqGrid demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) has many disadvantages. The oldest pages like the page, where `addRowData` are used, are mixed with another. By the way the data added by `addRowData` will be add to the current page. The page from "Loading Data"/"Array Data" has since year error in the line `for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)` (one should use `<` instead of `<=`). The information are organized historically ("New since beta 3.0" for example)  instead of showing the best practice in the current version.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with another answer from Jeffery_The_Wind. He don't wrote only the name of the option which he recommended: **`data` parameter**. It's important to add that one should use `gridview: true` option and don't use [afterInsertRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events) callback.

For the understanding: The usage of `addRowData` is the most slowly and ineffective way to fill the grid. The most problem is that if you insert an element on the page or change the element **at least the position of all existing elements** have to be recalculated by web browser. The more elements you placed on the page the more slowly will be inserting on the next one.

One solve the problem mostly in one from the two ways:

- one uses `DocumentFragment` to prepare detached hierarchy of DOM elements and then place the fragment in one operation on the page.
- one create the content of all or the most of the changes as string which represent HTML fragment and use `innerHTML` property to place many elements in one operation on the page.

jqGrid uses the second method. It's important to use `gridview: true` to have the behavior. So the recommended ways to fill local grid are:

- The usage of `datatype: 'local'` and `data` parameter with data. The standard format of the value of the input `data` parameter is the array with row items. Every item has the same properties like the value of `name` property of `colModel`. Additionally every item should has `id` property which defines the "rowid" - the id of the `<tr>` elements (the rows) of the grid. If you has another format of input data you have to use correspondent [localReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#array_data) parameter which describes the format of data.
- The usage of `datatype: 'jsonstring'` and `datastr` parameter which specify the input data. The value of `datastr` parameter can be either JSON string or JavaScript object with the same content. So if you have the data as object you don't need to convert it to JSON string using `JSON.stringify`. You can additionally use [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data) in the same format like you probably know for `datatype: 'json'`.

The main difference inserting of data from `data` parameter (in case of `datatype: 'local'`) and `datastr` parameter (in case of `datatype: 'jsonstring'`) is that the input data will be sorted by jqGrid in case of the usage of `data` parameter and will be included unsorted in case of `datastr` parameter.